# Fast jk Escape in Vim using ttimeout

Tags: vim, keymap

I recently came across the timeout and ttimeout features in vim.

I use the key sequence jk to escape from insert to normal mode. 
I thought, following this article [Mapping fast keycodes](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Mapping_fast_keycodes_in_terminal_Vim) [see 2b], that i could have my 
jk seqence obey the ttimeoutlen while all my other mappings obey timeoutlen. This would be ideal because i can hit jk really fast when i want to so it wouldnt interupt my typing when i need to insert a jk into a document.

However, following the above mentioned article, it didnt work for me. I went

```
:set timeout timeoutlen=1000 ttimeoutlen=100
:set <F13>=jk
:map <F13> <esc>
:map! <F13> <esc>
```

and pressing j in insert mode gives a delay determined by my timeoutlen, not my ttimeoutlen.

What am i doing wrong?  Is it even possible? Is it only possible for escape sequences? If so why? Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I turned off my comp, woke up, turned it back on and now it seems to work....

Also i changed the above code to:

```
set timeout timeoutlen=1000 ttimeoutlen=100
set <f13>=jk
imap <F13> <esc>
```

I had this set last night and it didnt work so i dont know what the 'nights rest' did...

Anyways, to all that use jk or any other alphabet sequence to escape from insert mode, i recommend doing this.

Comment: There seems to be inconsistencies in your code (f13 and F13 and I believe that I am more used to seeing <Esc> than <esc>), adjusting f13 to F13 and <esc> to <Esc>, the code did not work for me.